# Oracle date seems equals

Tags: oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

there is a table INCASSO in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE "GEC_AP"."INCASSO" 
("ID_INCASSO" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
 "ID_FATTURA" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "ID_PIANO_RATE" VARCHAR2(22 BYTE) DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL ENABLE,
 "DATA_ESECUZIONE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
 ...)
```

The primary key includes four fields:

```
CONSTRAINT "PK_INCASSO" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_INCASSO", "ID_FATTURA", "ID_PIANO_RATE", "DATA_ESECUZIONE")
```

It seems there is a duplicated record when I run the following query:

```
select id_incasso, id_fattura, id_piano_rate, data_esecuzione
from incasso
where id_incasso = 'TO_20110521258225'
```

[image]

But with another query, 0 records are extracted:

```
select id_incasso, id_fattura, id_piano_rate, data_esecuzione, count(*)
from incasso where id_incasso = 'TO_20110521258225'
group by id_incasso, id_fattura, id_piano_rate, data_esecuzione
having count(*) > 1
```

The database is on Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 and I'm using SQL Developer 4.1.1.19.

In SQL Developer, the date format is:

[image]

I would to know if the records are different or there is a format date problem in the editor. If the records are different based on the date, in which part of the date they are different? If it's a format date problem in the editor, how can I fix it?

Comment: Just query dump(id_incasso), dump(id_fattura),... and you will see difference

Comment: It is not necessarily the date.  There could be hidden characters in the string fields as well.

Comment: @Gordon - His second query returned zero rows. why? If records were any different, then second query should've shown it.

Comment: Try changing the date format to `DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS` - using `RR` might hide that one date is `11 AD` and the other is `2011 AD`.

Comment: And NLS format won't matter. the datatype is date. Second query must've shown the records if the dates were from different century

Comment: @GurV The first and second query aren't equal and dump will show why the first returns several rows. Output of SQL Developer misleading OP.

Comment: @niespolo What happens if you change the group by clause to: `group by trim(id_incasso), trim(id_fattura), trim(id_piano_rate), data_esecuzione` in your second query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the date format to `DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS` and you are likely to see the difference in that the dates have different centuries.

Using `RR` to format the year can hide that one date is `1911` and the other is `2011`

Try:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( DATE '2011-01-01', 'RR-MM-DD' ),
       TO_CHAR( DATE '1911-01-01', 'RR-MM-DD' )
FROM   DUAL
```

Both will output the same although they are different dates and will not be grouped together.

If the dates are still the same then look for additional spaces or other hidden characters in the strings; you can use `LENGTH()` to check the size of the strings or `DUMP()` to get the byte values of the contents:

```
select id_incasso,
       id_fattura,
       LENGTH( id_fattura ) AS f_length,
       id_piano_rate,
       LENGTH( id_piano_rate ) AS pr_length,
       TO_CHAR( data_esecuzione, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS data_esecuzione
from   incasso
where  id_incasso = 'TO_20110521258225'
```

Comment: The DATE column is unlikely to be the cause of the OP's problem, since the values shown in the results of the first query include the time and are the same for both rows. IMHO, it's the varchar2 columns which are suspect.

Comment: they're varchars, so trailing spaces should not occur. date does not have milliseconds, or does it, so this answer shows a very reasonable possibility.

Comment: @dlatikay DATE doesn't store milliseconds

Comment: @Boneist it is just as likely that someone input a date as the string `'11-AGO-11'` and oracle converted it (using the `YYYY` or `RR` year mask) and inserted it as `DATE '0011-08-11'` or `DATE '1911-08-11'` (if this is a legacy database that had data entered in the 90's) and the other row is `DATE '2011-08-11'`.

Comment: @dlatikay `VARCHAR2` columns can store a variable number of trailing spaces - you are probably thinking `CHAR` columns which right-pad with trailing spaces.

Comment: @MT0 So, if that's the case, the group by query must've given two rows, but it didn't

Comment: @GurV The `GROUP BY` query would not have returned two rows as it also has a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` clause so any unique rows would **not** be shown.

Comment: @MT0 ah, now I see where you were coming from; duh - I missed the fact that the years were two digits

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the date format used in SQL Developer to *DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS*
and the following query:

```
select id_incasso, id_fattura, id_piano_rate, data_esecuzione from incasso where id_incasso = 'TO_20110521258225'
```

show that the difference is in the year: [image: in the year]

Thanks everyone.