# Query issue with the where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

i am doing this query:

```
select xx.number, 
       xx.timestamp 
  from table xx
 where number = 6
   and timestamp = to_timestamp('09/09/99', 'DD/MM/RR');
```

where number = NUMBER(3,0) (can be repeated since its not a PK nor a FK) AND timestamp = TIMESTAMP(6) (can be repeated too).

There are records like this

```
9 - 09/09/99 00:00:00,000000000 
1 - 07/03/17 10:23:05,337000000
2 - 28/02/17 18:18:18,666000000
4 - 16/02/17 13:53:17,058000000
6 - 09/09/99 00:00:00,000000000
6 - 09/09/99 00:00:00,000000000
1 - 24/02/17 09:36:07,382000000
8 - 09/09/99 00:00:00,000000000
```

The problem is, when I do

```
select xx.number, 
       xx.timestamp 
  from table xx
 where timestamp = to_timestamp('09/09/99', 'DD/MM/RR');
```

it returns ONLY 1 eight and 1 nine (**NOT good**), it should have 2 sixes too

and when I do

```
select xx.number, 
       xx.timestamp 
  from table xx
 where number = 6;
```

it returns 2 sixes and its datetimes (good)

BUT when i do the query with both conditions it NEVER returns anything. I guess its because the first query returns the wrong output.

any ideas?

Comment: tried changing the AND to an OR?

Comment: I need it to have both conditions at the same time. if i change it for and OR, it does return everything, but i only need the ones with sixes and timestamp = 09/09/99 00:00:00,000000000

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41568532/1509264

Comment: On a sidenote: Why converting a string literal to timestamp? Use an ANSI timestamp or date literal instead: `where timestamp = date '1999-09-09'`.

Comment: Hello, Thorsten, the way you are telling me, does work, but its still not giving me any sixes in the output @Thorsten Kettner

Comment: No, that's why it's a sidenote :-) Have you checked MT0's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[TL/DR] Don't use the `RR` format model use `YYYY` and pass a 4-digit year when you are inserting and filtering data.**

The issue is likely to be in the `RR` format you are using to display and parse dates.

If you do:

```
select xx.number, 
       TO_CHAR( xx.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9 ) 
from   table xx
here   number IN (6, 8, 9);
```

I have a strong suspicion you will get the output:

```
9 1999-09-09 00:00:00.000000000 
6 2099-09-09 00:00:00.000000000
6 2099-09-09 00:00:00.000000000
8 1999-09-09 00:00:00.000000000
```

Where the century of the rows with number `6` is not `19` but either `00` or `20`.

So the reason that your timestamps are not matching is that they don't have the same century. You need to work out whether there is an error in the data in your table and if it should be the year `99`, `1999` or `2099` and fix that - then your query should work.

However, you should also investigate **why** this has occurred in the first place. Normally there is an insert statement using either:

- `TO_TIMESTAMP( your_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY' )` that is being passed an input in the format `09/09/99` so the database assumes the year is `0099`; or
- `TO_TIMESTAMP( your_date, 'DD/MM/YY' )` that is being passed an input in the format `09/09/99` so the database assumes the year is `2099` (in the current century) when you are expecting `1999` and should be using the format model `DD/MM/RR`.

A better fix would be to always use 4-digit years.

Comment: Doing a 

where number= '6'  and (
      timestamp>= to_timestamp('09/09/99 00:00:00,000000000','DD/MM/%%RR HH24:MI:SSXFF')
      and timestamp<= to_timestamp('09/09/9999 00:00:00,000000000','DD/MM/%%RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'))

it finally showed that the SIXES were XX/XX/8099...

Comment: @user2690047 There you go, the dates do not match as the centuries do not match. `8099` is a strange year to have and definitely warrants investigating where that century came from and whether it makes sense as a value (depending on your application, it may make sense).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'DD/MM/YY' as well and check if the same results are coming, because '99' could indicate 1899 as well in the Database (although unlikely)

Comment: changing it to: to_timestamp('09/09/99','DD/MM/YY'), it only returns the ones with number = 1... i dont get this...

Answer (score -1):

try this if you use 'group by' with Date it will work but if you use with time i will bring you multiple rows

```
 select xx.number, 
           cast(xx.timestamp  as date) as timestamp  
      from table xx
     where number = 6;
    group by number,cast(xx.timestamp  as date)
```